# uploading python files to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

Whenever I upload a python file to Google App Engine other than main.py, I get a 404 error when I try to load the site. For example here when I include the test.py section in the yaml, I get a 404 error on the entire site. Here is my yaml

```
    application: pythontest
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))


- url: /python/test.py
  static_files: test.py  

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

And my main.py

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

What would be causing this to happen?

Comment: It isn't clear from your post what exactly your problem is - what doesn't work?

Comment: My problem is that when I include the test.py section in the yaml, I get a 404 error on the entire site.

Comment: the threadsafe bit isn't supported with python2.5, are you sure that's not the issue? And should test.py be a static file? That would be unusual. Have you tried working through the guestbook example to familiarise yourself with how things work?